# XAML Reuse a block of markup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Consider I have multiple pages and I want to show the same "Header" in every page without copying & pasting it multiple times: it's very unmaintainable.

```xml
    <!--  #region Header  -->

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">

        <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource HeaderBackground}" />
        <TextBlock 
                   Style="{StaticResource PageTitle}"
                   Text="Page1" />
        <Button 
                Content="Settings"
                Command="{Binding GotoSettingsPage}" />

    </Grid>

    <!--  #endregion Header  -->
```

What are the options to make this block of markup reusable? For example it would be nice to write something like this:

```
<MyHeader Grid.Row="0" PageTitle="Page1" />
```

Comment: Create a `UserControl`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan But be careful with UI elements as resources. You should at least set `x:Shared` to false.

Comment: @Clemens It depends.

Answer (score 5):

A user control is an option.

MyHeader.Xaml:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App1.MyHeader"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource HeaderBackground}" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="Title"
                   Style="{StaticResource PageTitleStyle}"
                   Text="" />
        <Button Content="Settings"
                Command="{Binding GotoSettingsPage}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MyHeader.Xaml.cs:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App1
{
    public sealed partial class MyHeader : UserControl
    {
        public MyHeader()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string PageTitle
        {
            get { return Title.Text; }
            set { Title.Text = value ?? ""; }
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.Xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <local:MyHeader PageTitle="Page 1"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```